# Maven check if something is compiled

Tags: java, maven

I'm generating pom files for old projects. Then I test em with mvn clean compile install. But sometimes the sourceDirectory points to the wrong folder and there is no error. How could I check if there is actually is somthing compiled, without changing the code only the pom or the mvn call.

Greetings
Jeff

Comment: I manually check the output but it scrolls by so fast and -q has no use-able output.

Comment: The quick and dirty solution would be to look at the file size of the jars, and see if they are almost empty. And btw, `mvn clean install` is equivalent to `mvn clean compile install`.

Comment: it also depends on which ouput format you've declared in the `.pom` file

Comment: Jeff, the idea of maven is to have a reproducible build process. If the source directory `sometimes` points to the wrong place, it means that something in your pom (or parent pom chain) is changing something quite important. Rather than fix the symptom, why don't you fix the problem and fix your pom?

Comment: I'm generating the pom files for 100's of projects and most of the time I have the folder right but sometimes it is wrong. That's why I want to check it afterwards if the files were compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no sources compiled the file xxxx-sources.jar doesn't exist if you use the plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>attach-sources</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```